# Pasacal Triangle code is returning negative values. Why?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, pascals-triangle

Why is my code to find the 33th rowIndex of a Pascal Triangle giving me negative values?

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
        
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int k=0; k<=rowIndex; k++){
            int mCk = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
                mCk *= (rowIndex-i);
                mCk /= (i+1);
            }
            result.add(mCk);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Your input
33

Output

```
[1,33,528,5456,40920,237336,1107568,4272048,13884156,38567100,
 92561040,193536720,-3096621,-5002233,-7146047,-9051659,-10183116,
 -10183116,-9051658,-7146045,-5002231,-3096619,-1689064,-807813,
 -336588,-121171,-37283,-9665,-2071,-357,-47,-4,0,0]
```

Expected

```
[1,33,528,5456,40920,237336,1107568,4272048,13884156,38567100,
 92561040,193536720,354817320,573166440,818809200,1037158320,
 1166803110,1166803110,1037158320,818809200,573166440,354817320,
 193536720,92561040,38567100,13884156,4272048,1107568,237336,40920,
 5456,528,33,1]
```

Comment: It works fine for the values below 30. But if the rowIndex is 30 or higher, in the start it goes right but after some values it starts adding some random numbers.

Comment: Integer overflow.